# How to set fixed header footer and scrollable body text in ConstraintLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_32"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_40"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:text="HEADER"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_18"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_40"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_header">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/very_long_text"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:text="Footer"
        android:textColor="#00539f"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my layout I want to set a fixed header on the top fixed footer in the bottom and scrollable very long text in the body but when I used my code  bottom footer is overlapping with body text can anyone please suggest what properties I am missing I want to use only `ConstraintLayout` no Relative or `Linearlayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the bottom constraints of the scrollView to the top constraints of the footer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_32"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_40"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:text="HEADER"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_18"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_40"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_footer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_header">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/very_long_text"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:text="Footer"
        android:textColor="#00539f"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollable" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```